# How to manage costs by department

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-billing

We are in the process of developing a data lake to consolidate and manage data across various departments using a single GCP project.

Our objective is to ingest and process JSON data through Pub/Sub and DataFlow, subsequently storing it in specifically designed tables for each data within a single BigQuery dataset. For instance, our configuration is like:

```
project-id.common_dataset.table_for_datatype1
project-id.common_dataset.table_for_datatype2
```

We're interested in exploring methods to allocate the costs incurred by Pub/Sub, DataFlow, and BigQuery usage to individual departments.

Should the JSON data ingested by Pub/Sub include department-specific labels (for instance, {"department": "marketing",...}), is there good way to estimate the costs incurred for processing and storing each department's data through Pub/Sub, DataFlow, and BigQuery?

### example

Messages received by Pub/Sub should include the department, as follows.

```
{"department":"marketing", "log_type":"type1", "value":1}
{"department":"product1", "log_type":"type1", "value":1}
{"department":"marketing", "log_type":"type2", "amount":10, "date":"2024-03-06"}
{"department":"product1", "log_type":"type2", "amount":20, "date":"2024-03-05"}
{"department":"product2", "log_type":"type2", "amount":20, "date":"2024-03-04"}
```

For log_type=type1, the bigquery table is like project-id.common_dataset.type1

| department | value |
| --- | --- |
| marketing | 1 |
| product1 | 1 |

For log_type=type2, project-id.common_dataset.type2

| department | amount | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| marketing | 10 | 2024-03-06 |
| product1 | 20 | 2024-03-05 |
| product2 | 20 | 2024-03-04 |

What we ultimately want is this kind of estimated monthly cost for Pub/Sub, DataFlow, and BigQuery.

| department | Pub/Sub | DataFlow | BigQuery |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| marketing | 100 USD | 100 USD | 100 USD |
| product1 | 1000 USD | 1000 USD | 1000 USD |
| product2 | 500 USD | 500 USD | 500 USD |

Comment: You can use labels on your resources, then export the billing to BigQuery and group by labels

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I didn't know about exporting the billing!
I will take a look at the documentation.
https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates  
, https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/pipeline-options  

I tried using the PubSub_to_BigQuery_Flex template with these links.

I wanted to dynamically add "additional-user-labels" for each department per message to manage costs, but it looks like the labels are fixed per pipeline.

I will try to approximate using BigQuery data. Thank you.